# How to replace all values starting with certain characters in R with one value?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I hope this isn't a duplicate, I was unable to find a question that refers to the exact same issue.

I have a data frame in R, where within one column (let's call it 'Task') there are 170 items named EC1:EC170, I would like to replace them so that they just say 'EC' and don't have a number following them.

The important thing is that this column also has other types of values, that do not start with EC, so I don't just want to change the names of *all* values in the column, but only those that start with 'EC'.

In linux I would use 'sed' and replace 'EC*' with 'EC', but I don't know how to do that in R.

Comment: Sounds like simple replacement after you find the relevant values.  Try `Task[startsWith(Task, "EC")] <- "EC"`

Comment: Task is the name of the column, should I write df$task instead of task?

Comment: `transform(df, Task = replace(Task, startsWith(Task, "EC"), "EC"))`

Comment: Or for a sed-like regex solution: `df$Task <- gsub("^(EC).*", "\\1", df$Task)`

Comment: The startswith suggestion worked great, I did write df$task instead of just 'task'. Thanks a lot!  
this is what I used: df$task[startsWith(df$task, "EC")] <- "EC"

Comment: And thanks for the other suggestions, I am sure they will come in handy soon enough,

Answer (score 0):

Rich Scriven's startswith suggestion worked great, I did write df$task instead of just 'task'. Thanks a lot! this is what I used: df$task[startsWith(df$task, "EC")] <- "EC"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend regex as well. You're looking for string "EC" followed by 1 to 3 digits and replace these occurrences with "EC":

```
df$Task = sub("EC\\d{1,3}", "EC", df$Task)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something along these lines, but couldn't get the syntax straight.